# XCode cannot open project

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, macos, react-native

I'm new in IOS development
And i'm using react native inside a virtual MacOS in VMWare
But something happened, i can't open project in xcode
The error message is: **Could not open file. (/Users/User/Documets/Project)**
The project can be opened before, after building completing the android development, and i copied the full source code into this VM MacOs, the xcode won't run in this project anymore
I tried to reboot but still not work
Note: I'm new in MacOS so i don't know how to use it properly xD

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vi8R.png)

Comment: which folder have you opened with xcode?

Comment: Make sure you're opening the .xcworkspace file in the ios directory